# LCOV.INFO has absolute path for SF

Tags: sonarqube, karma-runner, istanbul, karma-coverage

I need to have relative path as value of SF: parameter in the lcov.info file generated by karma coverage. This is to enable SonarQube to gather the info to display the coverage.
Currently, the SF parameter is having complete absolute path , e.g. c:\abc\xyz....\src\bar\foo.js

I need to have SF: src\bar\foo.js

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately it is still impossible out of the box. To fix the issue you can either:

- use istanbul merged with [this](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/pull/771) request,
- process the output file using tools like `sed` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38290092/2865997)),
- generate the report from the same machine that Sonar scanning is performed ([original advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40861395/2865997)).