# How do a generate vscode TypeScript extension coverage report

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, code-coverage

It seems that coverage report with `coveralls` is not possible for VSCode extension built with TypeScript.

Currently, I am adding test cases to our project https://github.com/PicGo/vs-picgo/pull/42, I have found several ways to report coverages, but none of them work for me.

#### Using custom TestRunner

[The official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/testing-extension) mentions little about custom test runners, but I found a post [here](https://rpeshkov.net/blog/vscode-extension-coverage/). It works when I use `F5` to launch an `Extension Test`, but does not work when I run `npm run test` in the console (Got no coverage output at all).

I have also tried to understand the custom runner (source code) in the blog post, but I found I have nothing to do because I do not know why it works.

#### Using `nyc`

[`nyc`](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc) with mocha is very powerful, but we cannot take advantage of it. When I run `nyc ./node_modules/vscode/bin/test`, I will got 0% coverage:

[image: 20190525000930]

I have searched the issue page of `nyc`, lots of the same 0% coverage problems about TS projects exist, but none of them are the same with our environment. The main difference is that they are using `mocha` for testing, not like VSCode's `./node_modules/vscode/bin/test` script, it will create a new process to run the test js files. I don't know how to deal with this.

I searched all the issues (mocha, tyc, istanbul, vscode, etc...), and there are few (I did not find any  ) vscode TypeScripts are using coverage report for me to copy from. So my question is: how do I get the coverage report for my VSCode TS extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Add custom test runner

See [this post](https://rpeshkov.net/blog/vscode-extension-coverage/) for more information, you can just copy the [test runner code](https://github.com/rpeshkov/vscode-testcov/blob/master/test/index.ts) to your project's `test/index.ts` file.

### Demo azure pipeline configurations

```
variables:
  system.debug: true
jobs:
  - job: Windows
    pool:
      name: Hosted VS2017
      demands: npm
    steps:
      - task: NodeTool@0
        displayName: 'Use Node 12.3.1'
        inputs:
          versionSpec: 12.3.1
      - task: Npm@1
        displayName: 'Install dependencies'
        inputs:
          verbose: false

      - task: Npm@1
        displayName: 'Compile sources and run tests'
        inputs:
          command: custom
          verbose: false
          customCommand: 'test'

      # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45602358/lcov-info-has-absolute-path-for-sf
      - script: 'sed -i -- 's/..\\..\\//g' coverage/lcov.info && npm run coveralls'
        displayName: 'Publish code coverage'  
        env:
          COVERALLS_SERVICE_NAME: $(COVERALLS_SERVICE_NAME)
          COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN: $(COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN)

      - script: 'npm install -g vsce && vsce package'
        displayName: 'Build artifact'
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        inputs:
          contents: '*.vsix'
          TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
          pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
          artifactName: vs-picgo-dev-build
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'  # must quote since "*" is a YAML reserved character; we want a string
pr:
- dev*
```

Note that you have to use `sed` to delete the `..\..\` prefix of `SF` paths in `lcov.info`:

Before:

```
SF:..\..\src\vs-picgo\index.ts
```

After:

```
SF:src\vs-picgo\index.ts
```

Demo project: https://github.com/PicGo/vs-picgo

Answer (score 3):

I have struggled with this myself for some time until I got it working properly. There were three main challenges in getting it working:

1. Proper setup of the `nyc` instance
2. Preventing race conditions on startup
3. Capturing `nyc` output and displaying it in the debug console

You can find my working test runner [here](https://github.com/frenya/vscode-recall/blob/master/src/test/suite/index.ts). I'm also sharing additional insights on my [blog](https://frenya.net/blog/vscode-extension-code-coverage-nyc).

Comment: Please don't post the same thing multiple times! Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65804621/10871073), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65804630/10871073) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65804635/10871073).

Comment: This answer is great. I could solve my problem, I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70398369/10138996).

Answer (score 2):

I got everything working with Mocha, NYC, and VSCode!

You can see my solution to this in https://github.com/jedwards1211/vscode-extension-skeleton.

Basically, I use Babel to transpile my `.ts` code with `@babel/preset-typescript` and `babel-plugin-istanbul` before running the tests.  This allows me to skip the convoluted extra steps of instrumenting the `tsc` output and using `remap-istanbul`.

Then in the test runner, I use the (not really documented) NYC API to write the coverage to disk after tests finish.

Finally, in my package scripts, I run `nyc report` after the test command finishes.

**UPDATE**: you need to delete the `.nyc_output` folder before each test run too.

#### `src/test/index.js`

```
import NYC from 'nyc'

export async function run(): Promise<void> {
  const nyc = new NYC()
  await nyc.createTempDirectory()
  // Create the mocha test
  const mocha = new Mocha({
    ui: 'tdd',
  })
  mocha.useColors(true)

  const testsRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '..')

  const files: Array<string> = await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    glob(
      '**/**.test.js',
      {
        cwd: testsRoot,
      },
      (err, files) => {
        if (err) reject(err)
        else resolve(files)
      }
    )
  )

  // Add files to the test suite
  files.forEach(f => mocha.addFile(path.resolve(testsRoot, f)))

  const failures: number = await new Promise(resolve => mocha.run(resolve))
  await nyc.writeCoverageFile()

  if (failures > 0) {
    throw new Error(`${failures} tests failed.`)
  }
}
```