# Why does nyc does not gather test coverage for my project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, code-coverage, nyc

I am developing an [extension](https://github.com/pascalre/vscode-yaml-sort) for vscode using typescript. I set up a GitHub Action which is executing my test cases. To gather the test coverage I am using nyc.

These are my node scripts:

```
"compile": "tsc -p ./",
"test": "npm run compile && node ./out/test/runTest.js",
"coverage": "nyc npm run test"
```

When I run `npm run coverage` I see all my test cases are getting executed (they are not stored in the file `runTest.js`), but only the coverage for the test file `runTest.js` is gathered. The relevant classes `lib.ts` and `extension.ts` are not shown in the coverage.

Why is this so? What am I doing wrong?

See my [package.json](https://github.com/pascalre/vscode-yaml-sort/blob/develop/package.json) and [.nycrc.json](https://github.com/pascalre/vscode-yaml-sort/blob/develop/.nycrc.json) for configuration.

Comment: Just found out that the update from vscode 1.61 to 1.62 causes the problem. I do not know yet what's wrong with my configuration or how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix this problem by sticking to the great [blogpost](https://frenya.net/blog/vscode-extension-code-coverage-nyc) which I found [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65804621/10138996) on a similar Question.

The problem is, that NYC is a command line tool. When executing the test I focused on my configuration in the `.nycrc` file. Fact is, that the visual studio code test runner is not using this configuration and has to be configured inside the test runner.

I fixed the broken test coverage generation inside [this commit](https://github.com/pascalre/vscode-yaml-sort/commit/c57a8bcd973c2cc89945e4da69536af47eddb1fa).